# How to test rest request and response are same using soap ui?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am having the following request for create employee

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "dept": "mech",
  "dob": "20-Feb-1994"
}
```

i get response same and additionally id of an employee.
i am writing assertion to response for all properties like

```
"name":"${CreateEmp#Request#$.name}"
```

Is there any simple way to test the following conditions?

1. request and response are same (For Update)
2. request and response are same except id (For Create)

EDIT from Comments:

```
{  
   "empid":"4187",
   "deptId":"4",
   "branchId":"6",
   "firstName":"Prabhu",
   "lastName":"S",
   "emailAddress":"prabhus@gmail.com",
   "contactNumber":"987654321",
   "isEnabled":"Y",
   "dob":"02/05/1994",
   "doj":"03/04/2016",
   "fatherName":"XXXX",
   "motherName":"YYYY",
   "activationCode":"ssp",
   "spouseName":"ZZZZ",
   "address":"MMMMMM",
   "pincode":"123456",
   "district":"16",
   "dateCreated":"2017-02-21T13:00:24.317Z",
   "dateModified":"2017-02-21T13:00:24.317Z",
   "status":"0"
}
```

Comment: May be show raw sample response.

Comment: What kind of assertion have you added? Did the above one work ?

Comment: yes the above one worked successfully. for this i get 3-4 properties. i can do assertion like above. But i get above 20 properties for other json object. So i need is there any simple way to test whether request and response are same .

Comment: Would you please post the big response sample?

Comment: i posted rough data i cant post real data. {
  "empid": "4187",
  "deptId": "4",
  "branchId": "6",
  "firstName": "Prabhu",
  "lastName": "S",
  "emailAddress": "prabhus@gmail.com",
  "contactNumber": "987654321",
  "isEnabled": "Y",
  "dob": "02/05/1994",
  "doj": "03/04/2016",
  "fatherName": "XXXX",
  "motherName": "YYYY",
  "activationCode": "ssp",
  "spouseName": "ZZZZ",
  "spouseName": "ZZZZ",
  "address": "MMMMMM",
  "pincode": "123456",
  "district": "16",
  "dateCreated": "2017-02-21T13:00:24.317Z",
  "dateModified": "2017-02-21T13:00:24.317Z",
  "status": "0"
}

Comment: Thank you for that.Is the request & response appear the same in the above case too? Will you have to ignore any keys ?

Comment: here , my request same as response except empid, dateCreated, dateModified. While update dateModified and one or more fields need to modify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136274/discussion-between-rao-and-prabhu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the groovy script which does the response comparison against the request values

**Groovy Script:** Use this as `Script Assertion` for the request step, so that it can work with dynamically for any request and response instead of fixed json.

```
//Provide the keys to be ignored
def ignoreKeys = ['empid', 'dateCreated', 'dateModified']

def jsonRequest = context.rawRequest
def jsonResponse = context.response

def reqParsed = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonRequest)
def resParsed = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonResponse)

def sb = new StringBuffer()
reqParsed.keySet().each { key ->   
   if (!ignoreKeys.contains(key)) {
      reqParsed."$key" == resParsed."$key" ?: sb.append("${key} value does not match; request[${reqParsed."$key"}], response[${resParsed."$key"}]\n")

   }
}
if(sb.toString()) {
   throw new Error("There are differences between the request values and response values. Details below:\n${sb.toString()}")
}
```

Here you can try quickly online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5106737656889344)</kbd> with the fixed sample you have provided.

**Output:** Have used different values to domonstrate assert works

[image]